# Cannot access Boot Camp partition after OS X reinstall

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, startup

I've already used Boot Camp to install Windows on my computer. A while back I had to erase my hard drive and reinstall Mavericks. Once I did that my Windows portion still exist as a volume, but when I got to my Start Up Disk settings it's a folder and not a disk.

I have a lot of my music I created with sound effects and sound kits in FL Studios on that side I don't want to lose.

Do I have to erase and reinstall Windows using Boot Camp or can I fix that issue by creating another bootable disk for my Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the suggested proposals is advisable. If you erase and reinstall Windows all the music will be lost. Creating a second bootable disk is a complex and error-prone task.

If the Windows volume really still exists you can access it in read-only mode and save your music to the OS X volume by default. If you also need write access install an appropriate tool like [NTFS for Mac 14](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) or a free tool like [NTFS-3G for Mac OS X](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G).

You may also salvage the bootability of the Windows partition by adding appropriate MBR entries. Check for several questions and answers here at apple.stackexchange solving this issue.

Comment: What if I want to continue to use the boot camp Windows and have it open in my start up so I can have access to the Windows side to work in FL Studios? What can do in order for that to work?

Comment: @Rayne82 Would you mind opening Terminal.app and entering `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0` and `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`?. You have to enter your admin password after executing `sudo + some command`! Please add the results to your question by editing it. This shows the partition map - just to check if the Windows partition is still there.

Comment: It is suppose to be a folder icon for Windows! OS X appears as a disk icon. What you see is correct. Did you select the windows icon follow by a restart? If windows does not boot, you may have to rebuild the BCD file on the windows volume. This generally can be done by booting from the windows install media.

Comment: chakitathomas$ sudo gpt-r show/dev/disk0 sudofdisk/dev/disk0

WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

Password:
sudo: gpt-r: command not found
chakitas-imac:~ chakitathomas$ 
This what I got when I did the terminal

Comment: David how do you rebuild the BCD File for Windows?

Comment: @Rayne82 Please enter the commands properly with all spaces in between. You just have to copy and paste the content of the grey boxes in my first comment.

Comment: chakitathomas$ sudo gpt -r show/dev/disk0 sudufdisk0/dev/disk0 sudo+some command
Password:
gpt: unknown command: show/dev/disk0
chakitas-imac:~ chakitathomas$ 
-- 
I still have no clue what I'm doing.

Comment: @Rayne82 You are reading the partition table of your main disk. But you still don't enter the commands properly: I didn't write `sudo gpt -r show/dev/disk0` or `sudo gpt-r show/dev/disk0` but `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0`